# How to create a double digit integer list from a single digit integer list?

Tags: python, list

```
l=[1,4,5,6,3,2,4,0]
```

I want the to out come to be

```
newlist=[14,56,32,40]
```

I have tried

```
for i in l[::2]:
   newlist.append(i)
```

what to do

Comment: Important question: What output would you expect if there is 1 more item in you list i.e l=[1,4,5,6,3,2,4,0, 9]?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function within a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [1,4,5,6,3,2,4,0]
>>> [i*10+j for i,j in zip(lst[0::2],lst[1::2])]
[14, 56, 32, 40]
```

As a more general approach for covering the list with odd number of items you can use `itertools.izip_longest` (in python 3.X `itertools.zip_longest`) :
by passing the 0 as `fillvalue` argument:

```
>>> lst=[1,4,5,6,3,2,4]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [i*10+j for i,j in izip_longest(lst[0::2],lst[1::2], fillvalue=0)]
[14, 56, 32, 40]
```

Comment: you are missing the last element if the list has an odd number of elements. I've corrected that below

Comment: @EduardoCMB Indeed just updated with new alternative.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution, just for fun

```
lst = [1,4,5,6,3,2,4,0]
it = iter(lst)
for i in it:
  num = int(str(i) + str(next(it)))
  print num
```

Comment: You are also missing the last element of a list with an odd number of elements

Comment: Indeed, just asked the OP for his expectations in such scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1,4,5,6,3,2,4,0,1]
length = len(lst)
newList = [i*10+j for i,j in zip(lst[::2],lst[1::2])] 
if length % 2 == 1:
    newList.append(lst[-1]*10)

print newList
```

Output:

```
[14, 56, 32, 40, 10]
```